# Is this chain reaction facilitated by the relativistic Doppler shift possible?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, doppler-effect, pair-production

We consider a mirror moving at around 60% of the speed of light. 
Is this chain reaction facilitated by the relativistic Doppler shift possible?

We are on a reference frame tied to the mirror, in particular, to the nucleus of an atom in the mirror. A gamma photon with sufficient energy (more than 2mc^2,  where m is the rest mass of the electron) approaches the nucleus. The electron - positron pair is created. The electron transfers momentum to the nucleus. The positron is repelled by the Coulomb field of the nucleus, and annihilates with the electron of another atom in the mirror. Two gamma photons are created (at or slightly above the total threshold energy 2mc^2 , where m is the rest mass of the electron ). At about 60% of light speed, due to the relativistic Doppler effect, an observer on the mirror will see the frequency of each of the incoming gamma photon doubled (when moving straight towards the photon, all the possible geometrical configurations have to be considered, this is just a special case). That means that each of the two gamma photons that were released after annihilation, now can trigger pair creation events in the Coulomb fields of the nuclei of other atoms (this is exponential increase!!!). The process repeats, and at each step, momentum is transferred to the nuclei of the atoms of the mirror. This is the chain reaction facilitated by the relativistic Doppler shift.
Is this chain reaction possible in principle? If not, for what reason? Does the reason have anything to do with the conservation of energy and momentum?

Comment: If a positron-electron pair annihilate, they create two photons moving in opposite directions. Neither of these photons is likely to be capable of pair production, which requires an interaction with a nucleus in any case. There is no scenario where more than twice the incoming momentum of the photon can be transferred to the mirror, and usually it is less.

Comment: We can set the speed of the mirror such that even for the transverse Doppler shift,  at least one of photons will likely trigger a pair production event .

Comment: Well, the transverse Doppler shift is to the red, but this exact situation is not likely to happen.  Also, the angle between the directions of travel of the gamma photons  (after annihilation ) is not always 180°, (but likely close ) it depends on the momentum of the electron and positron.

Comment: I really don''t understand. The "transverse doppler shift" is a redshift due to something emitting photons that isn't in the same frame of reference as the nirror. Beyond interaction with the first photon, the mirror speed seems irrelevant. One of the emitted photons will leave the mirror (taking half the energy). Your cascade never happens because the remaining photon will eventually fall below the pair production threshold.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. First, the geometry does not allow it. Second, after the first annihilation,  the photons are  already in the mirror reference frame,  not in some absolute reference frame,  so there is no Dopple rshift. Thank you.